# Cannot load the @font-face

Tags: wordpress, fonts, font-face

I cannot get the font working on my Wordpress website, I tried everything and I cannot find what is wrong. I placed the font in the fonts folder created in the root of my wordpress blog.

Below you can see my style.css file.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'museo_sans500';
src: url('/fonts/museosans500-webfont.eot');
src: url('/fonts/museosans500-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('/fonts/museosans500-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('/fonts/museosans500-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('/fonts/museosans500-webfont.svg#museo_sans500') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}
```

and then calling it:

```
.myfont{    
font-family: "museo_sans500", sans-serif;
}
```

Any advice appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you placed the fonts in the root of you blog then your paths are incorrect. Right now you are pointing to the fonts folder in your current theme directory.

Comment: I meant the fonts folder is in the root, it should be ok, I dont think there is a problem with the path.

Comment: It is not a production site yet.

Comment: My guess your paths are incorrect. Everything else look right. If you are using chrome then use the dev tools and go to console(the last tab on the right) and see if you are getting any errors.

Comment: No problem. Glad you got it sorted out.